# Why is attr-map needed in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have looked through google and few books but couldn't find documentation about attr-map.

```
(c/defmacro ^:clojure-special-form throw
  "Throw to the catch for TAG and return VALUE from it.
  Both TAG and VALUE are evalled."
  {:arglists '([TAG VALUE])}
  [tag value]
```

Why is attr-map needed inspite of the params vector? Also can someone point me to a detailed resource about metadata in Clojure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not needed in that case. It's redundant.

```
user=> (defmacro ^:clojure-special-form throw   {:arglists '([TAG VALUE])} [tag value]   `(throw (Exception. ~tag ~value)))
#'user/throw
user=> (meta #'throw)
{:macro true, :ns #<Namespace user>, :name throw, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :line 41, :arglists ([TAG VALUE]), :tag :clojure-special-form}
```

compare with:

```
user=> (defmacro ^:clojure-special-form throw [tag value]   `(throw (Exception. ~tag ~value)))
#'user/throw
user=> (meta #'throw)
{:macro true, :ns #<Namespace user>, :name throw, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :line 43, :arglists ([tag value]), :tag :clojure-special-form}
```

See this explanation of [special forms](http://clojure.org/special_forms).

See also: [Learning Clojure: Meta Data](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_Clojure/Meta_Data)